# python3.10 installation on centos 7 with pip error

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, server, pip, centos7

I am trying to install python3.10 on vps and centos 7. I used following commends:

```
cd Python-3.10.10

./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install

sudo make altinstall

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 1

alias python3=python3.10
```

After this, I'm trying to install python libraries like `pip3 install pandas` but getting following errors:

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2zg3.png)

I already tried `pip install pandas --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`, but getting same error.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/